# How to use OAuth2.0 access token to retrieve gmail contact list

Tags: python-2.7, oauth-2.0, gdata-api, google-contacts-api

I use the following code to obtain access token for my application in Python.

```
 CLIENT_SECRETS = 'client_secrets.json'
 MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = "Missing Client Secrets"


 FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), CLIENT_SECRETS),
        scope=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'],
        message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

 storage = Storage('drive.dat')
 credentials = storage.get()
 credentials = run(FLOW, storage)
 http = httplib2.Http()
 http = credentials.authorize(http)
 service = build("drive", "v2", http=http)
```

But after obtaining the access token, how am I supposed to retrieve gmail contact list using gdata client library of Python? The sample in client library does not use OAuth authentication but another approach.

Comment: Can anyone suggest some good tutorial for this? I am newbie. Plz dont suggest developers.goole.com link... Any good links without this?

Comment: There's this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469685/how-to-grab-gmail-contact-list-after-user-gets-authenticated-with-oauth2